# Loop stops after the 13th round in bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have a folder `fasta_files` containing 500 files
Each file contains `fasta` sequence which is in this format

```
cat $file.fnn

>Fas1#66
EEYLKKFLMTSLVGFMYRMYKEYEVPDTDRNWTPKPSSAEFPGLKELKIKIDQLQLLLDTACSDESNTELTLLTLLEFIRAG
>Fas2#80
LQEWMPSYSKPTHTTKTLLSELITLVDTLKQETNDVPSESVVNTILSIADSCKTQTQKSKEAKTTIDSFLREH
.
.
.
>Fas3#87
VDTCASTCADTNVNTCASMCADTNVDTCASTCANTCASTEYTDLADPERIPLHIMQKTLNVPNELQADI
```

In addition, a got a blast file output which is in this format

```
Cat blastfile

Fas1#66 gi|1769046680|dbj|**BBO53957.1**|   100.000 0.0 1264    2654827 N/A N/A  
Fas1#66 gi|1769046681|dbj|**BBO53958.1**|   100.000 0.0 1117    2654827 N/A N/A  
Fas2#80 gi|1769046682|dbj|**BBO53959.1**|   100.000 0.0 1119    2654827 N/A N/A  
Fas3#87 gi|1769046683|dbj|**AWO53960.1**|   100.000 6.01e-118   339 2654827 N/A N/A
```

My aim is to make a connection between each of `fasta.fnn` with the  `blastfile` in order to obtain the value after the third pipe (mentioned with **bold**) in the blastfile like the output below

```
Cat $file.list    
BBO53957.1
BBO53958.1
BBO53959.1
AWO53960.1
```

I wrote this script which works

```
mkdir  fasta_files/lists
mkdir  fasta_files/fnn
echo "1" >counter

    for file in $(ls fasta_files/*.fnn) ;do


        cat $file|grep ">" |sed 's/>//'g|grep -wf- /home/kgee/DATA/blastfile |awk '{print $2}'|cut -d\| -f4 |sort -u >$file.list 
        mv $file.list  fasta_files/lists
        mv $file  fasta_files/fnn

        echo  "**" $(tail -1 counter) "** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED"
        awk '{print $1+1}' counter >>counter 

    done 
mv *list* lists
rm counter
```

The screen output is this:

```
** 1 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 2 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 3 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 4 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 5 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 6 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 7 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 8 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 9 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 10 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 11 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
** 12 ** LIST GENE FAMILIES FILES GENERATED
Cursor blinks for ever
```

All the 12 generated files `$file.list`  in the folder  `file.list` are exactly like I want.
My issue is that after the 13th time the loop brakes for a reason.
I removed the 13th file from the folder but again the loop "breaks" at the 13th time.
I removed all the files except 20 files and again "breaks" at the 13th time

Does anyone have any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: First, run your script through shellcheck: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: just before the `for` loop add `set -xv` to enable debugging; objective being to find out which command is hanging

Comment: Your awk is reading from the same file it's appending to...

Comment: Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: @Roadowl You are right. I'm really amateur on bash scripting but the checker works. It took me some time to edit it, but at the end  it works. Thank a lot !!!

Comment: @markp-fuso It stops again at 13th loop.

Comment: Sure, I didn't expect any change in behavior; but what did the debug output show you?  which command is hanging? what are the values of the variables in this pass through the loop?

Comment: @Shawn I used Roadwl's solution and it works, thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: @markp-fuso  I'm sorry, but I am an amateur on bash scripting, and I can't answer your question properly, but as far as I understand, it prints every line of my code using "+\n" each time.

Comment: update the question with the last 15 lines of output when running with `set -xv` enabled